# navigation between form in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i want to create a simple desktop application  i created the  interfaces using PyQt5
i have problem in navigation between interface  the first interface is login (class_name Ui_Login_) second one is  register (Ui_Register_Form)
i created tow function but i faced the same problem they  stop in  'self.ui.setupUi(self.ui)'

those are  my function

```
    def openwindow(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget
   
    self.ui = register.Ui_Register_Form
  
    self.ui.setupUi(self.ui)
   
    self.window.show()
```

and the second function i tried is

```
 def openwindow(self, checked):
    if self.w is None:
        self.w = register.Ui_Register_Form()
        self.w.show()

    else:
        self.w.close()  # Close window.
        self.w = None  # Discard reference.
```

i called boutgh of them using this code

```
self.Register_Button.clicked.connect(self.openwindow)
```

Comment: Change to `self.ui.setupUi(self.window)`.

Comment: @musicamante same problem  but this time  app stop automatically

Comment: You missed the parentheses after `Ui_Register_Form`

Comment: @musicamante  i edited  the code as you said and  i used try catch  it stop   after ( self.ui = register.Ui_Register_Form)

Comment: Did you add the parentheses to `Ui_Register_Form` as said above?

Comment: yes i did  , it could be a problem in  different area of code  ?  cause i tried different way but it did not work( same problem) i created the file from .ui file i did not code it except this function and  the code to display

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

i want to thank @musicamante for his time
i tried to work with  tow variables and it's work as a new developer  still do not know  the real reason but i think the function broke because i want one parameter to handle tow variables in one time

```
 def openwindow(self):
        self.regui = QtWidgets.QWidget()          
        self.ui = register.Ui_Register_Form()           
        self.ui.setupUi(self.regui) 
        self.regui.show()
```

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @MaciejBledkowski i had a problem in this function i found the problem where it is and  i solve it  why it's not an answer